# Why is an XPath expression returning an element with just one child?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML file. It contains C# documentation comments exported by MSBuild (if that's relevant).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
  <assembly>
    <name>Test</name>
  </assembly>
  <members>
    <member name="T:Test.TestClass`2">
      <summary>
        This is just a test class.
      </summary>
      <typeparam name="T1">A generic parameter.</typeparam>
      <typeparam name="T2">Another generic parameter.</typeparam>
      <remarks>
        It is used to test the library.

        <typeparamref name="T1"/> is a very nice generic parameter.
      </remarks>
      <seealso>
        Don't see also
      </seealso>
    </member>
    <member name="P:Test.TestClass`2.TestProperty">
      <summary>
        This is a property of the <see cref="T:Test.TestClass"/> class.
      </summary>
      <value>
        Always returns 0.
      </value>
      <seealso>
        Don't see also
      </seealso>
    </member>
    <member name="M:Test.TestClass`2.Generic`1(System.Int32,System.Collections.Generic.List{`0},System.Collections.Generic.List{`3})">
      <summary>
        Test of the generic parameters handling.
      </summary>
    </member>
    <member name="M:Test.TestClass`2.DoTheJob(System.String,System.Int32)">
      <param name="str">A string.</param>
      <param name="integer">A 32-bit integer.</param>
      <remarks>
        A dummy method. Don't pass 3 to <paramref name="integer"/>.
      </remarks>
    </member>
    <member name="T:Test.AnotherTestClass">
      <summary>
        A nice little class.
      </summary>
    </member>
    <member name="E:Test.AnotherTestClass.MyEvent">
      <summary>
        Occurs very frequently.
      </summary>
      <example>
        anotherTestClass.MyEvent += MyHandler;
      </example>
    </member>
    <member name="F:Test.AnotherTestClass.StructureOfTheWorld">
      Some idiot put this text here.
      <summary>
        Contains the <c>structure</c> of the world.
      </summary>
      <remarks>
        Includes:

        <list type="bullet">
          <item>
            <term>Stars</term>
            <description>Large shining spheres</description>
          </item>
          <item>
            <term>Planets</term>
            <description>Smaller spheres that go around stars</description>
          </item>
          <item>
            <term>Planets</term>
            <description>Smaller spheres that go around stars</description>
          </item>
          <item>
            <term>Black holes</term>
            <description>Very curious objects</description>
          </item>
        </list>
      </remarks>
    </member>
    <member name="M:Test.AnotherTestClass.#ctor(System.Type)">
      <summary>
        This is a constructor.
      </summary>
      <seealso>
        <list type="bullet">
          <item>I</item>
          <item>Mum</item>
          <item>Dad</item>
          <item>Grandad</item>
          <item>Grandma</item>
          <item>Brother</item>
          <item>Sister</item>
        </list>
      </seealso>
    </member>
    <member name="M:Test.AnotherTestClass.op_Implicit(Test.AnotherTestClass)~System.String">
      <summary>
        Just calls ToString().
      </summary>
      <remarks>
        Do not use.
      </remarks>
    </member>
  </members>
</doc>
```

I want to inspect `member` elements one-by-one, searching them by names. I'm using this XPath expression:

```xml
//member[@name='{insert_name_to_be_inspected_here}']
```

which works, but for some curious reason the `member` element it returns only has one child element, even if there are more.

If I search for `T:Test.AnotherTestClass`, it returns this XML (the indents are copied precisely):

```xml
<summary>
        A nice little class.
      </summary>
```

If I search for `` T:Test.TestClass`2 ``, it returns this:

```xml
<summary>
        This is just a test class.
      </summary>
```

So where are the `remarks`, `typeparam` etc elements?

Comment: It depends on the language and code used to parse the xml. Without that it's hard to tell.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal reproducible example is not provided. So, I am shooting from the hip.

Please find below a solution based on LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string xmlFile = @"e:\Temp\SNBS.xml";
    string memeberName = "T:Test.TestClass`2";
    
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

    var xelem = xdoc.Descendants("member")
      .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == memeberName);
      
    Console.WriteLine(xelem);
}
```

**Output**

```
<member name="T:Test.TestClass`2">
  <summary>This is just a test class.</summary>
  <typeparam name="T1">A generic parameter.</typeparam>
  <typeparam name="T2">Another generic parameter.</typeparam>
  <remarks>It is used to test the library.

                <typeparamref name="T1" />is a very nice generic parameter.</remarks>
  <seealso>Don't see also</seealso>
</member>
```

Comment: Thank you. Probably it wasn't very clever to head to XPath for such a simple task.

Comment: Good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. 
Please mark it as answered. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). 
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted"

Comment: I think it's obvious from my >200 reputation that I know how to accept an answer. I didn't do it though because I wasn't able to try the solution immediately after I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

> but for some curious reason the member element it returns only has one child element

How do you know? What is it that tells you it has only one child element? It seems to me more likely that the XPath expression is returning the correct result, and something is going wrong subsequently in the way you display or examine this result.